# Data bind the index of an item in a listbox?

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a set of local high scores (ObservableCollection) and they're data bound to a ListBox so I can display them. Here's what I currently have, the "{Binding Index}" of the first TextBlock is where I'm trying to grab the index of the current item but I'm not entirely sure if it's possible through data binding:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="localScoresListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="90" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}"       Grid.Column="0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlayerName}"  Grid.Column="1" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Score}"       Grid.Column="2" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

So my question. Using data binding, can you grab the index of the current item?

If it is possible I believe it would be 0-based and since I want the first rank to be 1 instead of 0, could you do something like {Binding Index+1}?

EDIT: There's a similar question here for WPF and there didn't seem to be a way to do it then either: [WPF ListBox bind to index of the item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259092/wpf-listbox-bind-to-index-of-the-item)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of - especially since the item that you are binding will be of whatever type your object is, and it probably doesn't have an Index property.

I'd suggest adding the index property to your data objects (it can be added / manipulated when you populate the collection).